# TWebResponse is not parsing my posted files

Tags: delphi, rest, post, delphi-xe3

I have a simple DataSnap REST server, on the TWebModule I have added a action to listen to a POST request on the path "/upload_file".
On the onAction event I have this code:

```
procedure TWebModule.WebModulePostFileAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var i: Integer;
  str: String;
begin
  for i :=0 to Request.Files.Count-1 do
  Begin
    Str:= Str +','+ Request.Files.Items[i].FileName;
    // I will like to save or move the uploaded file to i.e. c:\myFiles\
  End;
  Response.Content:= Str;
end;
```

Request.Files.Count is always 0, but when I inspect the Request.content object, I can see the multipart file content. how can I get the posted file out of the request? and save it some where in the disk.
My HTML form from where I m posting looks like:

```
<form action="/upload_file" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Notes: <input type="text" name="notes"/>
  File: <input type="file" name="my_file"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Unfortunately there is no much info about this subject, I been trying many thing for hours but not success.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: xxm can handle multipart/form-data file uploads natively, there's even support to read the upload progress from other requests: http://xxm.sourceforge.net/ there's an example here https://sourceforge.net/p/xxm/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Delphi/demo2/09%20Upload%20Progress/

Comment: Unfortunately my project is using DataSnap, and write another app to just handle uploads, seem to me add to much complexity to my existing project. thanks for the advice tho.

Answer (score 0):

See related question [TIdHTTPServer file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191402/tidhttpserver-file-upload) and answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6197138/80901:

> TIdHTTPServer does not currently support multipart/form-data
>   submissions natively. That is on the todo list for Indy 11. In the
>   meantime, you have to parse the posted MIME data manually using
>   TIdDecoderMIME, as mjn suggested. There have been examples of that
>   posted in the Embarcadero and Indy forums before.

Comment: I m actually looking for a way to handle this through DataSnap, not Indy; but is a good idea to use the TIdDecoderMIME to parse the data out. I will keep trying and I will post my code in case I figure things out. Thanks for the answer tho.

Comment: IIRC DataSnap internally uses Indy - so unless DataSnap implements this missing feature somehow else, the linked workaround are an option