# Delphi upload image HTTP server

Tags: delphi, file-upload, httpserver, forms, http-post

In my VCL application I have an http server. I am trying to upload an image from a browser. Here is the code of the commandGet procedure:

```
procedure TForm6.HTTPServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  imageStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  if Pos('command=addImage', ARequestInfo.UnparsedParams) > 0 then
  begin
    AResponseInfo.ContentText := UploadImageForm;
  end
  else if Pos('command=saveImage', ARequestInfo.UnparsedParams) > 0 then
  begin
    imageStream := TMemoryStream.Create;

    try
      ARequestInfo.PostStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      imageStream.LoadFromStream(ARequestInfo.PostStream);
      imageStream.SaveToFile('picture.jpeg');
    finally
      imageStream.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Here is the code of UploadImageForm:

```
 function UploadImageForm: string;
 var
   uploadImageHTMLForm: TStringBuilder;
 begin
   uploadImageHTMLForm := TStringBuilder.Create;

   try
     // by default enctype is application/x-www-form-urlencoded
     // uploadImageHTMLForm.AppendLine('<form action="/?command=saveImage" method="post">');
     // EDIT
     uploadImageHTMLForm.AppendLine('<form action="/?command=saveImage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
     uploadImageHTMLForm.AppendLine('<input type="file" name="uploadField">');
     uploadImageHTMLForm.AppendLine('<input type="submit">');
     uploadImageHTMLForm.AppendLine('</form>');
     Result := uploadImageHTMLForm.ToString;
   finally
     uploadImageHTMLForm.Free;
   end;
 end;
```

The problem is that when I select a .jpeg file and click submit ARequestInfo.PostStream is empty (I create it onCreatePostStream). Any idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML form `<input>` elements with `type=file` should use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2436725/80901).

However, multipart/form-data is not supported by TIdHTTPServer - see [TIdHTTPServer file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191402/tidhttpserver-file-upload)

Additional code is required to extract the file content from the request body. (There have been examples of that posted in the Embarcadero and Indy forums before.)

Comment: which property of aRequestInfo (RawHeaders, PostStream or another) should I use. Can you post a link because I haven't found something useful yet

Comment: See http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.internet.winsock/201107/1107276163.html

Comment: thank you for the useful sourse. You helped me again to solve my problem :)